# MySQL Query to fetch count of values from whole table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql with values as given value

```
+--------+---+---+---+---+----+
+ emp_no + A + B + C + D +  E +
+--------+---+---+---+---+----+
+ 100    + 1 + 0 + 2 + 1 +  1 +
+ 101    + 2 + 1 + 1 + 3 +  1 +
+ 102    + 3 + 4 + 4 + 2 +  5 +
+ 103    + 5 + 3 + 4 + 1 +  2 +
+--------+---+---+---+---+----+
```

Is it possible for me to write a sql query which will fetch me total count  of 1,total count  of 2,total count  of 3....from the aforesaid table.Any help toward this is  deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That ASCII art is trippy... notice how the dashes seem to bend/curve? Or am I losing it?

Comment: Search for the SQL `COUNT()` function. It may have what you need.

Comment: @rvi I think he need to count column with variables table

Comment: I can suggest to receive all data in array into script and count all 'not-id' variables into script.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT num, SUM(counts) FROM (
SELECT A num, COUNT(A) counts FROM table1 GROUP BY A
union all
SELECT B num, COUNT(B) counts FROM table1 GROUP BY B
union all
SELECT C num, COUNT(C) counts FROM table1 GROUP BY C
union all
SELECT D num, COUNT(D) counts FROM table1 GROUP BY D
union all
SELECT E num, COUNT(E) counts FROM table1 GROUP BY E
) temp 
GROUP BY num
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is a little bit complicated.  Here is a way, by unpivoting the values and then aggregating:

```
select val, count(*)
from (select emp_no,
             (case when n.n = 1 then A
                   when n.n = 2 then B
                   when n.n = 3 then C
                   when n.n = 4 then D
                   when n.n = 5 then E
              end) as val
      from table t cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
           ) n
     ) e;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) with sum of boolean conditions. Check this out:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        (`a` = 1)
        +
        (`b` = 1)
        +
        (`c` = 1)
        +
        (`d` = 1)
        +
        (`e` = 1)
    ) as `1`,
    SUM(
        (`a` = 2)
        +
        (`b` = 2)
        +
        (`c` = 2)
        +
        (`d` = 2)
        +
        (`e` = 2)
    ) as `2`,
    SUM(
        (`a` = 3)
        +
        (`b` = 3)
        +
        (`c` = 3)
        +
        (`d` = 3)
        +
        (`e` = 3)
    ) as `3`,
    SUM(
        (`a` = 4)
        +
        (`b` = 4)
        +
        (`c` = 4)
        +
        (`d` = 4)
        +
        (`e` = 4)
    ) as `4`,
    SUM(
        (`a` = 5)
        +
        (`b` = 5)
        +
        (`c` = 5)
        +
        (`d` = 5)
        +
        (`e` = 5)
    ) as `5`
FROM
    `table`;
```